# Directory used in Command line to Compile&Run .java file

Tags: jvm, java

I installed JDK on my PC running windows XP, the default directory of JDK is :

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin

I'm following the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html#win32-2b)  to do a sample
My **source file** named **HelloWorld** is in another directory : `E:\NotePad\Code`

As the tutorial says : "To compile your source file, change your current directory to the directory where your file is located" , so I change my Command's current directory to `E:\NotePad\Code` , but here comes the problem which is saying **'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command**

Well, the tutorial has a [solution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html)  to this problem, it seems that I should change Command Line's **current directory** to where the JDK is installed which is : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin`

After I finish it, I try this commond : `javac HelloWorld.java` to compile the file, but it says

> javac : cannot find file : HelloWorld.java

It means that the **HelloWorld.java** file in `E:\NotePad\Code` can't be compiled by the JDK which is installed in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin`
I try putting the **HelloWorld.java** file in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin` , it works fine

So the question is : **How can I Compile&Run a file with the JDK installed in a different directory** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will either need `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin` on your `PATH`, or reference the compiler directly using

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\javac
```

Comment: by saying **reference the compiler directly using C:\Program Files ...** , do you mean put the source file in that JDK installed directory ?

Comment: No. Leave your code in the E: drive and just change the path such that you can find the compiler regardless of which directory you're in

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to update your PATH variable, see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#path

Comment: yes, I've followed that solution, and it works, but I was wondering if there is some other way to solve it